# How can I fix this error when trying to deploy my svelte app on github pages?

Tags: github-pages, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to deploy my svelte app on GitHub Pages and cannot get rid of these errors I get from running 'npm run build'.

The exact errors are:

```
(node:15364) ExperimentalWarning: buffer.Blob is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
file:///C:/Isabella/personal-website/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/prerender.js:460
                                throw new Error(format_error(details, config));
                                  ^
Error: 404 /src/images/github.png (linked from /)
    at file:///C:/Isabella/personal-website/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/prerender.js:460:11
    at save (file:///C:/Isabella/personal-website/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/prerender.js:744:4)
    at visit (file:///C:/Isabella/personal-website/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/prerender.js:635:3)
[vite-plugin-svelte-kit] Prerendering failed with code 1
error during build:
Error: Prerendering failed with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Isabella/personal-website/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/vite.js:2367:14)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```

And here is my svelte.config.js file:

```
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  preprocess: preprocess(),
    kit: {
        // target: '#svelte',
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',  // path to public directory
            assets: 'build',  // path to public directory
            fallback: null,
        }),
        prerender: {
            // This can be false if you're using a fallback (i.e. SPA mode)
            default: true
          }
    }
};

export default config;
```

Comment: Please do *not* screenshot code, include it as formatted text instead. Also, the terminal seems to additional error information higher up, but is cut off by the scroll viewport.

Comment: How do you try to get the `github.png` image in your code?

Comment: (Yes, 404 errors should not happend during a static page build.)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're linking to `/src/images/github.png` in `index.svelte` but the prerenderer can't find the file because it tries to look for the file in the default assets folder `static`.

To fix it change the link to the correct path and put the image in the static folder (i.e. `images/github.png` if you put the images folder in the static folder).