# Svelte production build error : Prerendering failed with code 1

Tags: javascript, svelte

I received a frontend for a website that I am trying to deploy. Running it locally in development mode works (`npm run dev`). However, now I am trying to build it for use in production (`npm run build`) but I am getting the following exception:

```
file:///Users/stan/IdeaProjects/runespawn/web-frontend/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/prerender/prerender.js:50
                                throw new Error(format_error(details, config));
                                      ^

Error: 404 /
    at file:///Users/stan/IdeaProjects/runespawn/web-frontend/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/prerender/prerender.js:50:11
    at save (file:///Users/stan/IdeaProjects/runespawn/web-frontend/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/prerender/prerender.js:332:4)
    at visit (file:///Users/stan/IdeaProjects/runespawn/web-frontend/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/prerender/prerender.js:196:3)
[vite-plugin-svelte-kit] Prerendering failed with code 1
error during build:
Error: Prerendering failed with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (file:///Users/stan/IdeaProjects/runespawn/web-frontend/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/index.js:443:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
```

I have found a similar question [How can I fix this error when trying to deploy my svelte app on github pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73230057/how-can-i-fix-this-error-when-trying-to-deploy-my-svelte-app-on-github-pages) but in this case the error actually makes it very clear what path is wrong. In my case, I have no idea how I can find the invalid path, Svelte does not tell me where it is.

I have inherited this project from a frontend developer, I am not familiar with Svelte or javascript in general. Any help to troubleshoot would be much appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and although I don't think this an ideal solution, ignoring the prerendering errors worked. In your `svelte.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
      pages: 'build',
      assets: 'build',
      fallback: null,
      precompress: false  
    }),
    prerender: {
      onError: () => {
        return "continue";
      }
    }
  }
```